# Checkboxfield value controls button visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `gridview` which displays the contents of a database table in rows. There is a `CheckboxField` there and a `Select` button. I want to set button visibility to false when checkboxfield is checked.

this is my aspx page:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsViewERgo" runat="server" Height="50px"
    Width="100%" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" 
    DataSourceID="LinqDataSourceErgo" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    HeaderText="Σύντομη Περιγραφή Επιλεγμένου Έργου">      
    <Columns>
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Diekperewsi" HeaderText="Answered" 
            SortExpression="Diekperewsi" Visible="True" 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:CheckBoxField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert Answer" ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <center>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Select" Text="Επιλογή" Visible="true" >
                    </asp:Button>
                </center>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have tried this but only works with checkboxes

```
protected void GridViewAitima_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("Diekperewsi");
        Button b = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("Button1");
        if (!cb.Checked)
        {
            b.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            b.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no such control 'Apantisi' in your .aspx??

Comment: You'd better narrow down the problem, add less code and be more precise in your explanation.

Comment: Isn't using client side script an option for this toggle ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will run on the server side but it looks as if the the `AutoPostBack` property for your checkbox is not set to true -

```
AutoPostBack="True"
```

so when the checkbox is checked the code will not run immediately, it will only run after another event has caused your page to postback.

Comment: There is no AutoPostBack definition for CheckboxField

Comment: I must admit I can't recall ever using the property, but there are some MSDN docs for it here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

CheckBoxField has no id thus you can't find it by id, moreover it has no value propertie.
I suggest you use template field just like you used for the button, but instead put a checkbox in it.

so instead of :

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Diekperewsi" HeaderText="Answered" 
                    SortExpression="Diekperewsi" Visible="True" 
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:CheckBoxField>
```

put :

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="Diekperewsi" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Eval("Diekperewsi")%>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

and you are good